# #REF Excel Error Add-in

Tags: excel, function, add-in

I have an Excel Addin that generate data from database.
after loading data on sheet (sheet1) , I write excel functions(in sheet2)depending on that data , at the beginning it works great, but when I re-exrcute my function(sheet1)and then refresh the sheet2 I get the #REF error !!

```
=+MAX(SUM(Table1[[#ALL];[column1]]);SUM(Table1[[#ALL];[Column2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Invalid cell reference errors occur when a spreadsheet formula contains incorrect cell references. This happens most often when:

1. Columns or rows containing data used in the formula are accidentally deleted.
2. A formula has been moved or copied to another cell and the cell references are incorrect.
3. Data used in a formula has been moved, leaving the function or formula with incorrect cell references

You need to go through it and find the error I'm afraid manually.

Is generating data operation generate same line count every time? If second generating operation generates less then first generation, your function couldn't find lines at the end and generate #REF error.

Comment: in fact when I re-execute my function (sheet1) it delete old cells and replace them with new ones ,but the table remains the same (same columns same data same number) , even with that i Get the #REF! error

Comment: I find something like that table1[@[column1]:[column1]] , could you try this. Also this can help you http://www.excelcampus.com/tools/absolute-reference-add-in/

Comment: the problem remain :/ 
I did not install this new add-in , but I tried it manually and I still get the #REF! error
(I think there is no @ in the tuto)

Answer (score 0):

Is the table name changing when you run the add-in to generate data from the database?  Your formula references Table1, but it is possible that the table name changes when you re-generate it using the add-in.